# Getting Tab Component To Consume UIID

Tags: codenameone

I have tried everything possible to style my Tab component but its not getting reflected. I want my selected Tab to have a white background and red foreground. Even though I have edited Style using Theme designer. Its still doesnt work. I read the docs and I am aware Tab component is now like a toggle. I did the suggestion to setTabUIID(null) but still cant get it to work. How can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `setTabUIID(null);` just make sure to style both selected and unselected styles. Also override the Border to `Empty` if you don't define a border.

Comment: I have tried all that Shai and still no changes. Infact when I edit the selected styles to what I want and click ok, it restores to the original default Tab style. When I click edit, it shows what I want (with a white background etc) and when I click OK again, it restores.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnQi3.png

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "pressed" the selected tab style is really the pressed style

Comment: great...works now....Now I get the ToggleButton idea...I have edited your answer for correctness